# Connect to API endpoint with Angular factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to connect with API endpoint via the simplest AngularJS snippet but have some problems which are stopping me.

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('appController', ['$scope', 'skills',
 function($scope, skills) {
 skills.success(function(data) {
  $scope.skillsList = data;
});
  }
]);
```

And my factory:

```
app.factory('skills', ['$http', function($http) { 
  return $http.get('https://www.persevy.com/skills') 
        .success(function(data) { 
          return data; 
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
          return err; 
        }); 
}]);
```

I have even prepared a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BsFSQ98yCsvPqzGw83il?p=preview) for this but also without success, please tell me where is the problem in the above code.

Comment: look like CORS issue..accessing different domain

Comment: Code seems solid, got this in the console XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.persevy.com/skills. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: ok how to fix it and allow access?

Comment: What is your API written into? (Rails by any chance?)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems related to [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) : basically, you cannot access a domain via Ajax if it's not allowed on the server side. This is a "security" feature on most modern browser. You won't encounter this problem using command line such as `curl` or `Postman` chrome's extention.

If you own the domain https://www.persevy.com/, make sure the domain requesting the data is allowed in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, as well as the http verb (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`... or `*` for every http methods).

If you are using an API, you should find something in the documentation regarding that matters.

**Edit**

I'm a bit rusty in RoR, but from my googling, looks like you can use the [rails-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem, or try [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dhoelzgen/cd7126b8652229d32eb4).

Basically, it comes down to add the two following headers to the server's response :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
```

Comment: but is should be allowed to access from the same domain yes?

Comment: No, you have to specifically allow the domains on the server side. You can allow all the domains for tests purpose, using `*` Can you tell us what language your server is using ? It's a browser feature, if you post data using `curl` you won't have this problem

Comment: that is true, from `curl` I can access without problems, this application is written in RoR, how to allow it?

Comment: My Rail is rusty, but Google for CORS Rails, and you should find what you are looking for. See edit

Answer (score 1):

In your `RoR API` in app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :add_allow_origin_headers

def add_allow_origin_headers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.headers['Origin'] || '*'                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
end
```

Or you can use a `gem` called `rack-cors`

```
#Gemfile
gem 'rack-cors'

#config/application.rb
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
   allow do
     origins '*'
     resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
   end
end
```

This will allow the requests from different applications, fixing the issue for you. 
More information on the [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem [here](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors)